# Optimize a function several times R code

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I have a function. From this I can estimate parameters easily.

```
sex <- c("F","M","F","M","F")
age <- rnorm(5,28,1.2) 
dat <- data.frame(sex,age)
myfun <- function(par, x1,x2){

    -sum(log(exp(par[1]*x1+par[2]*x2)))
}
myf <- optim(myfun, par=c(0.1,0.4), x1=dat$age,x2=as.numeric(dat$sex))$par
```

I want to optimize this function 10 times. If I use `replicate(10,myf)` then it gives same values 10 times. But I guess it will give some different parameter estimates every time due to `age <- rnorm(5,28,1.2)`. I want to do this using loop, how can I proceed?

Comment: Use `replicate` on the entire code chunk, not just the optimization part.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you need, but would that work for you?

```
myfun <- function(par, x1,x2){

  -sum(log(exp(par[1]*x1+par[2]*x2)))
}

sex <- c("F","M","F","M","F")

for (i in 1:10){
age <- rnorm(5,28,1.2) 
dat <- data.frame(sex,age)
print(optim(myfun, par=c(0.1,0.4), x1=dat$age,x2=as.numeric(dat$sex))$par)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
myf <- sapply(
  split(dat, 1:nrow(dat)),
  function(dat.row) optim(myfun, par=c(0.1,0.4), x1=dat.row$age,x2=as.numeric(dat.row$sex))$par
)
```

Produces:

```
             1         2         3         4         5
[1,] 23.861664 24.517216 26.823635 24.913725 24.573490
[2,]  4.806402  4.911159  5.459353  4.943076  5.214703
```

Where each column is the result of one run of `optim`.